Can we use same xpath for both browser automation and Windows hybrid app automation?
I have full set of automation for my product using Selenium WebDriver for browsers. Now I want to automate the same product in Windows hybrid app where the webview contains my product.
How can I automate with the same xpath and id which is used for web browser automation in this hybrid Windows app?
I'm getting no such element exception when tried with the same id and path.
Can someone please clarify it with the required dependencies?

In which framework the hybrid application is built?

Its built in UWP framework and webview2 @jonrsharpe

Do you have any suggestion @SA

Try chromedriver. it should work with win UI 2 @PrakashFrancis
